# Entity Framework, Code-First, Mapping linking table

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-code-first

I'm writing a WebAPI RESTful service backed onto a MySQL database using C# VS2017.
Let me start by stating that I have been unable to get the MySQL integration working correctly to implement Datbase-first design, so I'm going the other way round and implementing code-first.
I've tried following all the articles I could find to get database-first to work, but nothing has worked as expected - I get various errors at various stages, but umtimately, I'm unable to implement database first.

So, going Code-first, I have a scenario that I am unsure how to map it.

I have the following entities / tables:
Stundents - self explanatory
Classes - details of a class
Year - details of the various years
StudentClass - linking table between students and classes, such that each student can be in multiple classes.
The StudentClass table however also has an additional field - YearId ensuring that the StudentClass link is only valid for a single, specific year.

The Student table has a StudentId, the Class table has a ClassId and the Year table has the YearId all as the primary keys.
The StudentClass table has the following fields - all comprising the Primary Key:
StudentId, ClassId, YearId

The Student class contains all the fields for the Student table as well as the following, linking it to the list of classes:

```
public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
```

The Class class contains all the fields for the Class table as well as the following, linking a single class to multiple students:
    public virtual ICollection Students { get; set; }

My DatabaseContext class has the following:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Year> Years { get; set; }
```

In the OnModelCreating method it also has the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
  .HasMany<Class>(s => s.Classes)
  .WithMany(c => c.Students)
  .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("studentID");
        cs.MapRightKey("classID");
        cs.ToTable("studentclass");
    });
```

While this works nicely for linking students to classes, this has no bearing on the Year in any way.

What do I need to do in order to be able to include the YearId in the link / entity so that the object itself represents a student, with all their classes for a given year?

Comment: So you want the student object, having a list of years and in those years the classes she followed?